# Is there a way to add header to apache response on how long it took to retrieve a resource?

Tags: apache

Is there a module or a built-in function in apache which I can use/activate to send information how long it took to retrieve/process a resource?

For example the resource http://dom.net/resource is accessed. The response header will include the total time it took to wait for the resource to be ready before it gets sent back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Apache doesn't really 'wait' until the resource is ready before sending the response back to you - it streams data back to the client as and when it receives it.

Depending on what you're interested in measuring, you could record the time taken for the client to receive the first byte/last byte back from Apache, or measure the time taken for Apache to receive the first byte from the (remote?) resource [like so](https://serverfault.com/a/65180). The time taken for Apache to receive the entire response back from the remote resource is not something you can send in the headers, as the headers will have been sent to the client before the remote response is fully received. This information could trivially be written to the Apache logs, however.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I'm interested to know how long it took for the server to request the resource and the first byte received. This is the case for cgi scripts not really for static resources like images

Comment: Well, in that case the answer I linked to should be able to help you out. If you don't want to send the duration in the headers, you could always add the `%D` flag to your LogFormat configuration, [like so](http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/06/apache-logs-how-long-does-it-take-to-serve-a-request/)